# React Hook "useState" is called inside condition, but not condition is inside

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

After to read this page:
https://typeofnan.dev/fix-the-react-hook-is-called-conditionally-error-in-react/

I try to find the error but i keep getting the error:

React Hook "useState" is called conditionally

here the code:

```
export const PageSettings = (props) => {
  const {
    table,
    listviewFields,
    t,
    tableCrud,
    updatePageSettingsFields,
    templates,
    visibleFields,
    visibleFieldsToggle,
  } = props;

  let aFields = [];
  let aFieldsForSortable = [];
  for (const [keyName, fieldSet] of Object.entries(listviewFields)) {
    const listViewField = table.listview.fields[keyName];
    let fieldSource;
    if (listViewField.virtual) {
      // virtual don't throw error, must have always label
      fieldSource = listViewField;
    } else {
      fieldSource = table.fields[keyName];
    }
    const field = table.fields[keyName];

    const { aColHeaderToAdd, titleFieldFull, printCell } = getHeaderToAdd(
      listViewField,
      keyName,
      fieldSource,
      table,
      props,
      t,
      templates,
      tableCrud,
      fieldSet,
      listviewFields
    );

    if (printCell) {
      aFieldsForSortable.push({ id: keyName, name: titleFieldFull });
      aFields.push(
        <div
          key={keyName}
          style={{
            fontSize: "12px",
            minWidth: "90px",
            maxWidtht: "150px",
            bgColor:
              listviewFields && listviewFields[keyName].invisible === true
                ? "black"
                : "green",
          }}
        >
          <input
            type="checkbox"
            name={keyName}
            style={{}}
            checked={
              !listviewFields[keyName].invisible ||
              listviewFields[keyName].invisible === false
                ? true
                : false
            }
            onChange={updatePageSettingsFields}
          />
          <label htmlFor={keyName}>{titleFieldFull}</label>
        </div>
      );
    }
  }

  const [stateList, setStateList] = useState([aFieldsForSortable]);

  return (
    <div
      style={{
        display: "flex",
        flexDirection: "row",
        alignItems: "center",
        color: "#FFFFFF",
        paddingTop: "20px",
        width: "100%",
        backgroundColor: visibleFields ? "#555555" : null,
      }}
    >
      <a onClick={visibleFieldsToggle}>
        <ShowIcon icon="eyecheck" color="#5f97c1" />
      </a>
      <ReactSortable list={stateList} setList={setStateList}>
        {state.map((item) => (
          <div key={item.id}>{item.name}</div>
        ))}
      </ReactSortable>
      {visibleFields && aFields}
    </div>
  );
};

const getHeaderToAdd = (
  listViewField,
  keyName,
  fieldSource,
  table,
  props,
  t,
  templates,
  tableCrud,
  fieldSet,
  listviewFields
) => {
  let colsHeader = [];
  let printCell = true;
  // Logic Twin TT103
  let titleField;
  let titleFieldFull;
  // fieldSource can be not exist, by example , virtual field: customers.listview.addresses2
  if (
    fieldSource &&
    fieldSource.fieldDisplayedOptions &&
    fieldSource.fieldDisplayedOptions.separatorsubfield === "col"
  ) {
    /*
  not call main field, but the subfields to get label
   */
    for (const [nameSubField, objField] of Object.entries(
      fieldSource.fieldDisplayedOptions.subfields
    )) {
      titleField = resolveListLabel(table.related[keyName].table, nameSubField); // look for related table
      titleFieldFull =
        titleFieldFull + (titleFieldFull ? " " : "") + titleField;
      colsHeader.push(
        <div className="cell" key={nameSubField + keyName}>
          {t(titleField)}
        </div>
      );
    }
  } else {
    if (listViewField.module) {
      if (
        !resolvePathObj(
          props,
          "myState.app.appSettings.modules." + listViewField.module,
          true
        )
      ) {
        //if (keyName === 'dateaccounting') console.log('module not compat', props);
        printCell = false;
      }
    }
    if (listViewField.templates) {
      if (
        !intersection(
          listViewField.templates,
          templates,
          props.tableCrud,
          keyName
        )
      ) {
        //if (keyName === 'dateaccounting') console.log('no template');
        printCell = false;
      }
    }
  }
  /*if (keyName === 'dateaccounting') {
    console.log('module, propstemplates, templates', listViewField.module, templates, listViewField.templates);
  }*/

  if (printCell) {
    titleFieldFull = resolveListLabel(tableCrud, keyName);

    // try find short word, if not exist then get normal word
    let title = t(titleFieldFull + "_short");
    if (title === titleFieldFull + "_short") title = t(titleFieldFull);
    titleFieldFull = title;

    colsHeader.push(
      <div className="cell" key={keyName}>
        {titleFieldFull}
      </div>
    );
  }
  return { titleFieldFull, printCell, colsHeader };
};
```

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're passing the argument `aFieldsForSortable` which is initialized as `[]` and then conditionally (inside the if statement), you're writing information for that value.

I'd suggest starting the use state as empty and in case you're changing it, call the `setStateList` method. For example,

```
const [stateList, setStateList] = useState([]);

....

if (printCell) {
    const aFieldsForSortable = stateList;
    aFieldsForSortable.push({ id: keyName, name: titleFieldFull });
    setStateList(aFieldsForSortable);
```

Comment: I think your code may trigger an infinite loop. `setStateList()` will trigger a re-render, which would cause `aFieldsForSortable` to be calculated again, which would call `setStateList()` again, which would trigger another re-render... I think the code involving `aFieldsForSortable` needs to be put in a `useEffect()` hook to avoid the infinite loop.

Answer (score 0):

You are breaking the [**Rules of Hooks**](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html).

Rules of Hooks say:

> Only Call Hooks at the Top Level
> Don’t call Hooks inside loops, conditions, or nested functions

The `useState()` call should be at the top of your function. If your initial state is based on a complex calculation, then you should do that calculation inside `useEffect()` (setting the value using `setStateList()`), otherwise the complex calculation will be re-run every time your Component is re-rendered.